# Python wtforms: change textfield value after entry

Tags: python, textfield, wtforms

I am modifying a Python / WTFORMs form.

There is a TextField which I want to intercept, check and possibly amend immediately after entry or before the form is submitted.

I've looked at the relevant documentation but it is not clear how to do this.

I don't mind if I use a built-in function or even find a way to insert some Javascript to work with the rendered HTML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that MyForm is a wtform class
you can recreate it like this

```
field_value = "some new value"
myform = MyForm(field_name=field_value)
```